# <select> containing time from specific start hour into end another specific hour

Tags: php, drop-down-menu

i need your help in this problem,

i have this empty dropdownlist:

```html
echo"<select id='time' class='form-control'>";
  
echo"</select>";
```

i have for example 2 hours: 8:30 and 12:30, i want to fill it by using PHP, with time from 8:30 into 12 just like this:

8:30

9

9:30

10

10:30

11

11:30

12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use DateTime class.

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->setTime(8, 0);
$h = 8;
while($h <= 12){
   $date->add(date_interval_create_from_date_string('30 minutes'));
   echo '<option>' . $date->format("H:i") . '</option>';
   $h = (int)$date->format("H");
}
```

Comment: do you have a link ? where can i find this class?

Comment: It is builtin php class. You dont need to do anything. http://php.net/manual/tr/class.datetime.php